# WordPress home page is shown, but not the other pages of the site

Tags: apache-2.2, apache-2.4, wordpress

I just uploaded my new site (in WordPress) and all pages except from the home page, isn't shown. I get the message:

> **Not Found**
> The requested URL was not found on this server.

what may go wrong?

Contents of the Apache error log:

```
[Tue Jun 07 13:29:07.152338 2016] [core:error] [pid 24925] [client 168.123.123.121:56503] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.,
[Tue Jun 07 13:29:12.931493 2016] [core:error] [pid 24937] [client 168.123.123.121:56555] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:29:53.005937 2016] [core:error] [pid 24944] [client 168.123.123.121:56560] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:40:28.624742 2016] [core:error] [pid 25153] [client 150.140.129.79:63334] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:40:49.138136 2016] [core:error] [pid 25154] [client 168.123.123.121:56653] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:40:50.246925 2016] [core:error] [pid 25155] [client 168.123.123.121:56654] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:40:50.922086 2016] [core:error] [pid 25156] [client 168.123.123.121:56655] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Tue Jun 07 13:40:51.396859 2016] [core:error] [pid 25157] [client 168.123.123.121:56656] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

Comment: What does apache error log says? There should be some hint.

Comment: well, this is a problem, as I don't have access to the Apache.. is sth I can do, or is this is sth that is related to the apache , so only the administrator can solve this.. ?

Comment: Redirection can also be carried out by directives in `.htaccess` so it's still possible that you can resolve the issue. You should [edit] to include the contents of this file.

Comment: Also, the Apache version is either 2.2 or 2.4. It can't be both.